# How to reset my terminal prompt to default - post mess-up

Tags: terminal, bash

Whether or not it was a mess up, this seems to be over my head, and further reading would only get me deeper in trouble. Hence am posting here:

What happened (verbose b/c I am not sure which is relevant):

I was doing "git push" when I was prompted to fix the author name and user email. I copied the command and did it. The command opened an editor (vi), but I didn't know how to close the editor's window. So I closed the Terminal window (w/o editing).

At some point, I was prompted to switch to `zsh` from `bash`. I copied the prompt and did it.

Problem is: the prompt became `myName@MacBook-Pro %` (used to be `My-MacBook-Pro $`). To remove the `%` and set the prompt back to default, I read some and followed a tip and did `export PS1="\W \$"` which resulted in my prompt becoming `\W \$`. So I did `export PS1="$"`, thinking at least I could get rid of the clutter. But whatever I did, it didn't stick. When I open a new window, the same `myName@MacBook-Pro %` reappeared.

Set aside what git wants me to do regarding username, how do I get my prompt to get back to default, with username (or MacBook-Pro) and current working directory--most importantly, ending in $ (and not %, which is driving me bananas)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're using zsh now not bash?

*The following applies to zsh:*

**To make your change persistent you have to include the `export PS1` line in your `~/.zshrc` file.** If you already have such a file, open it and check for an `export PS1` line and edit it to suit your needs.

If not, run:

```
echo 'export PS1="%M $ "' >> ~/.zshrc
```

which will change your prompt to include the full machine host name followed by $ as requested ([see here for more details](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html)).

To see the effects of this change you either need to open a new terminal window or source the `.zshrc` file (in every terminal that was open when you made the change):

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

You can achieve the same results in bash but using either the `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` files (and not forgetting to source them).

---

*A little aside:*

I'm sure you've done your research by now but if you get stuck in vim again, the following key combination will help: `ESC : q <CR>` (where `<CR>` is the enter key). If you've made changes though this won't work. You can either discard the changes:

```
ESC : q! <CR>
```

or write the changes to file:

```
ESC : wq <CR>
```

If your experience didn't scare you off from vim, here's a great cheat sheet I'd recommend: https://vim.rtorr.com/

Comment: I have sorta cobbled together a solution, but this response and the tips here helped me understand what happened and how to properly exit the VIM editor. As you suspected, I didn't have the `.zshrc` file in the system. So creating  `.zshrc` was step one. The first line of suggested code above (starting w `echo`) - followed by an explanation - is helpful in decoding the cheat sheet. Thanks!